# How to get a resource's path from the app using an Android Library?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, sdk, android-library

I'm using an Android Library (SDK A) and it has a customize option.

This option is used like this example below:

```kotlin
val sdk = SDK_A()
sdk.customizeFont("font/myFont.ttf")
sdk.show()
```

It means this library will look for "myFont.ttf" inside fonts folder to show something using my custom font.

My main goal is to make a new Android Library (SDK B) that uses this library and let users of my library have access to this customisation, they will need to place their custom fonts somewhere my library can access.

My library should be used like this:

```kotlin
val sdk = SDK_B()
sdk.customizeFont("font/myFont.ttf") // it could have another approach, like resource id or something like this
sdk.show()
```

Summing up, users of SDK B will have a custom font and will set it using **sdk.customizeFont** method from SDK B, SDK B will set this same font using **sdk.customizeFont** method of SDK A.

I cannot change SDK A, I can make changes to SDK B and tell users how to use it.

SDK A: Needs to use some path like "font/myFont.ttf" to know where the font is.

SDK B: Needs to know where the font is to set the path on SDK A, doesn't need to have the same approach.

Anyone have a good idea on how to solve it?

Comment: "How to get a resource's path" -- resources do not have filesystem paths on the Android device. "Anyone have a good idea on how to solve it?" -- how to solve *what*? You already wrote what would appear to be the solution: "users of SDK B will have a custom font and will set it using sdk.customizeFont method from SDK B, SDK B will set this same font using sdk.customizeFont method of SDK A". But, that suggests that I do not understand what the problem is.

Comment: When the user of SDK B uses sdk_b.customizeFont("font/myFont.ttf"), SDK B uses sdk_a.customizeFont("font/myFont.ttf") and SDK A show a message of font not found, my guess is that SDK A is looking for the font on files of SDK B, not on user's files. You know what I mean?

Comment: Since we do now know what "SDK A" is, we cannot comment on what its `customizeFont()` function is expecting as a parameter. SDKs do not have files, so "SDK A is looking for the font on files of SDK B" does not really have meaning in Android. You will need to read the documentation for SDK A, or contact its developers, to find out what exactly `customizeFont()` is expecting. Or, perhaps tell us what SDK A actually is (with links and stuff), and perhaps we can provide some advice that way.

Comment: Nice explanation, I knew I was wrong about something, I just didn't know what.

You can check SDK A [here](https://cardinaldocs.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CMSDK/pages/957710348/Challenge+User+InterfaceCustomization+Android-+V+2.2.3).

I'm using kotlin on my Android Library.

Comment: I didn't know that Atlassian spaces could be publicly accessible... I do not see `customizeFont()` on that page. I see a bunch of font-related methods, such as `setTextFontName()`. An entry in their [FAQ](https://cardinaldocs.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CMSDK/pages/876052486/Android+Frequently+Asked+Questions) indicates that the parameter is a relative path inside `assets/` of the app. So the app or SDK B would need `main/assets/font/myFont.ttf` for `font/myFont.ttf` to work as a parameter value.

Comment: customizeFont is an example of setTextFontName. I will try to use main/assets/font/myFont.ttf path. Thank you.

Comment: To be clear, the font file goes in `main/assets/font/myFont.ttf` in your module. You would then pass `font/myFont.ttf` to `setTextFontName()`.

Comment: That's exactly what I tried and it keeps showing "font not found" error.

Comment: Use Android's Studio's APK Analyzer to confirm that your font file is the expected location. If it is, then perhaps Cardinal's docs are out of date. You would have to contact them for support.

Comment: Solved it. I created an assets folder (app/src/main/assets/font) and placed ```"myFont.ttf"``` there, then I set this font like ```sdk_b.setTextFontName("font/myFont.ttf")``` and now it's working just fine because of your comments. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware):

> To be clear, the font file goes in `main/assets/font/myFont.ttf` in your module. You would then pass `font/myFont.ttf` to `setTextFontName()`.

On my test app using SDK B, I placed `myFont.ttf` in `app/main/src/main/assets/font` and set it using `sdk_b.setTextFontName("font/myFont.ttf")`.